# Authorisation for Sinatra via CanCan

Tags: ruby, sinatra, authorization, cancan

I am trying to get some auth mechanism working for my webapp (written in Sinatra). Currently I am playing around with sinatra-can which looks great. The issue I now face is that I need access to the specific model from the can method. Lets say I have a route that looks like that:

```
class ProjMgmt < Sinatra::Base
  get '/edit/:project' do 
    project = Project.where(name: param[:project]).first
    authorize! :edit, project
    project.to_html
  end
end
```

There are two models defined, `Project` and `Manager`. They are stored in a MongoDB (via mongoid, NO datamapper, ActiveRecord or so) and have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation, eg. the relations can be accessed via `project.managers` or `manager.projects`.

Now, only managers that have a relation to the particular project should be able to edit the project. What I want to have is something like that on `authorize!`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :edit, project if project.managers.include? user
  end
end
```

Obviously, that does not work since `Ability` does not know about any `project`.

Is there any nice approach to this? Must not necessarily be CanCan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
def initialize(user)
  can :edit, Project do |project|
    project.managers.include? user
  end
end
```